# Pandas Pivot_Table grouped values

Tags: python, pandas, pivot-table

I have a large data set on a CSV ([Dataset](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-soi/15zpallagi.csv)). I want to create a pd.pivot_table to summarize the data by zip code, however, my data has lines that share the same zip code.

```
df = pd.read_csv('15zpallagi.csv')
df['A00100'] = df['A00100'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)
df.pivot_table(values='A00100', index='zipcode', aggfunc='sum')
```

When I run the code above to create a pivot_table, the value column includes several values, like if it was stacking on the sum with multiple values.
[image: output of pivot table]

However if run the following code, I get the same values, but in an understandable format. 
[image: results of pivot with columns]

```
df.pivot_table(values='A00100', index='zipcode',columns='agi_stub', aggfunc='sum')
```

How can I create a pivot table that just adds the column A00100 and gives me a total by zip code?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please don't include links to data, or to images of output.  Instead, create a [mcve] with example data and expected output, which represents the issue you're seeing in your data.  (Often you only need to provide a small subset of the data you're working with to demonstrate the issue - or even fake data that reflects the qualities of your actual data, in the case that your data are sensitive or otherwise unshareable.)  That will make it a lot easier to help you, and it's also a good way to ensure your question is clear to others in the future (links can break).

Answer (score 2):

You are likely seeing these inconsistencies because this line `df['A00100'] = df['A00100'].map('{:,.2f}'.format)` is converting your A00100 column to a string type instead of a float.

Comment out that second line and try again to see if that fixes the issue.

If you need to format the number to only show 2 decimals, do that after all of your transformations.

If you are rounding for some other reason (significant figures, etc.), use the [Dataframe.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html) function instead of string formatting.